# ¿Cómo saber cual será el ID que está ingresando a la base de datos?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema, quiero saber cual es el id que se está almacenando en la base de datos.
En este caso quiero saber del registro que trae laravel.

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $email = array('@','gmail.com','hotmail.com','-','.');
        $code = str_replace($email,"",$data['email']);
        $date = str_replace('-','',date('Y-m-d'));

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'code'  => 'x0'.$code.'0x_free'.'_'.$date,
        ]);
      // Saber el id que se está registrando en la DB.
    }
```

Quiero saber el ID que para poder crear datos a una tabla relacionada, en este caso licencias.
Esto es lo que usaba cuando yo creaba mis propios formularios, pero en este caso, intenté hacerlo y no me funcionó.

```
$user->id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Usando `New User`

```
$user = new User();
$user->name        = $data['name'];
$user->email       = $data['email'];
$user->password    = bcrypt($data['password']);
$user->code        = 'x0'.$code.'0x_free'.'_'.$date;
$user->save();
dd($user->id); // Esto es el id del usuario nuevo

// Y por ultimo retornamos $user

return $user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba obteniendo el **id** de esta manera:

```
$id = $this->create($data)->id;
```

Y para la misma función, puedes intentarlo así:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
 {
    $email = array('@','gmail.com','hotmail.com','-','.');
    $code = str_replace($email,"",$data['email']);
    $date = str_replace('-','',date('Y-m-d'));

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'code'  => 'x0'.$code.'0x_free'.'_'.$date,
    ]);
    // Saber el id que se está registrando en la DB.
    $ID = $user->id;
    //return...
}
```